# filter notifications from 'notifications' table 'data' field - Laravel

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-5.3

This is the default laravel `notifications` `data` field

```
{
  "type":"Update Appointment",
  "appointment_id":"379",
  "date":null,
  "updated_by":"Mahir",
  "status":"2"
}
```

In `controller` i want to get all notifications with `status = 2` and mark as read

Laravel 5.3 doc shows

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->unreadNotifications as $notification) {
    $notification->markAsRead();
}
```

How do i modify this to get all notifications with `status = 2`

Update : looking for something like this

```
$noti = $user->unreadNotifications->where('data->status',"2");
```

Note : my database doesn't support `json` data type.

Comment: seriously, know one answered :(

Answer (score 5):

According to laravel 5.6:  [JSON Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#json-where-clauses)

and work with MySQL 5.7

I hope this answer help you

Answer (score 2):

```
$user = $user->unreadNotifications->where('data.complaint_id',1);
```

Its work fine for me, I hope it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can create your own channel, (see also Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\DatabaseChannel), where you can  override send() method, for saving your notifications. Before that, you can write your migration to update "notifications" table to add your custom  filtering field.
See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#custom-channels

Sorry for my English. Hope, you'll understand.